# Is swap method in C# whose parameters have value type not efficient?

Tags: c#, .net, methods, parameters

Check this method:

```
public static void Swap(ref int i, ref int j)
{
   int aux=i;
   i=j;
   j=aux;
}
```

Is it more efficient than this?

```
public static void Swap1(int[] a, int i, int j)
{
   int aux=a[i];
   a[i]= a[j];
   a[j]=aux;
}
```

I'm using these methods like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] a = { 5, 4, 3, 1 };
    Swap(a[1], a[2]);
    Swap(a, 1, 2);
}
```

Which of these methods is more efficient and why?

Comment: watch this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552731/c-good-best-implementation-of-swap-method]

Comment: next time pls try not to totally modify question after 40 min, ask new one ;P

Comment: It makes no difference, the x64 jitter in particular generates the *exact* same code for both.  As it should.  Don't sweat the small stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method will not swap any parameters at all. I mean it will swap parameters inside your method, but it will not affect the values of source parameters. That's because value types **are copied** when they are passed into methods. Here's the example:

```
void IncorrectSwap(int a, int b)
{
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

void HereHappensNothing()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    IncorrectSwap(a, b);
    // a still = 1, and b = 2, nothing happens
}
```

To make your method work you have to pass value types by reference like that:

```
void CorrectSwap(ref int a, ref int b)
{
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

void HereSwapHappens()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    CorrectSwap(ref a,ref b);
    // a = 2, and b = 1, Ok.
}
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) you can read about value types and how to work with them.

**Update**

Following your update. I don't think there should be any significant difference in performance as long as [value types don't get boxed when passed by ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx). There can be some penalty when you pass more parameters, but I don't think it should be significant, you will not see the difference.

Comment: Maybe not express myself well, question fixed, sorry

Answer (score 2):

Not passing by `ref` will not work. As you will only be affecting the local parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does nothing!
When parameters are passed by value you can't change them.
So to correctly implement Swap you need to pass by ref.